# How to remove Single Remote notification in iphone

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am developing game which have support of server side push notification of score and winning notification, User game request.

All is working fine with notification read and response store to device side. But when notification is pushing to notification center. when i click on notification at that time it remove all the push notification from notification center with following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

But i want to remove selected remote notification from notification center.

Is there any way to remove single remote notification.Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To cancel **local** notifications

If you have the means to obtain a reference to the specific UILocalNotification instance you want to cancel, you can call `cancelLocalNotification:` on it.

Try traversing all scheduled notifications in order to obtain that reference by going through:

```
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

---

To cancel **remote** notifications

This is entirely up to the server, can't be done without proper API on the server's side.

Comment: i am using above code in following method:
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

But it gives me array value as null.

Comment: I think you're confusing two completely different things: You can't cancel a scheduled remote push notification (it's scheduled on the server) - you can only cancel local notifications.

Comment: when notification is fired from server side it fired in our device notification center if there are more then 1 notification of single application at that time. when i select single notification at that time i need to delete that selected notification from notification center.

Comment: Oh OK, sorry. I misunderstood the question.